# How to load API data into Azure Synapse?

Tags: azure, api, etl, azure-synapse

I want to load below given API data to Azure Synapse Workspace

```
https://data.nj.gov/resource/pruu-wapw.json
```

I didn't find any helping material to load this API data into Azure Synapse Serverless SQL Pool.

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is copy task, you can use Azure data factory to copy data from the API to the synapse.

you need to follow the below steps:

1. you would need to create a REST linked service and a dataset and since this is a shared API, you can use anonymous authentication

[image]

2. In copy activity, REST dataset would be your source and synapse would be your sink.

Comment: exactly this is the answer, we can also do the same inside Copy data tool option of Integrate inside Azure Synapse Analytics